# Parsing Xpath 2 with xsi:type="term:term"

Tags: xpath

What is the correct XPath expression to filter the two description values out of the following XML:

```
<course>
    <description>This is a description of the course</description>
    <description xsi:type="learning:outcome">This is the description of the learning outcome of the course</description>
</course>
```

I thought the correct XPath would have been:

```
//course/description[@xsi:type=""]
//course/description[@xsi:type="learning:outcome"]
```

But this does not work when tried in XMLSpy or in my importer in Drupal 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistyped xsi:type as xsi:path.

Also you need to be sure that the xsi namespace is declared in the XPath context.